# How to only return the value itself from php to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I've looked around on the internet for answers, but I couldn't find any specific to my situation. As mentioned in the title, i'm trying to retrieve and then display a certain value from mysql database.

Disregarding the security measures which I will add later on, I've managed to retrieve the data, but when I send it back to the javascript and alert it, this value is returned: {"acc_points":"5"}. I would like it it to be just "5", is there any way that I can do this? Thanks!

Here are the codes:

**js file**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#viewpoints").click(function() {

        {
            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1/MP/apppoints.php?callback=?",
                    dataType: 'JSONP',
                    async: false,
                    jsonp : "callback",
                    jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",

                    success: function jsonpcallback(response) 
                    {

                        alert(JSON.stringify(response));

                    }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

**php file**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

require 'dbcon.php';

session_start();

$acc_id = $_SESSION["acc_id"];

$sql = "SELECT acc_points FROM  points WHERE acc_id = '$acc_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$acc_points = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if($acc_points != null)
  {
      $response = $acc_points;
      echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($response) . ')';
  }
  else
  {
      $response = "Failed. Please try again.";
      echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($response) . ')';
  }  
    //connection closed
    mysqli_close ($con);

?>
```

Comment: Could it not just be alert(response.acc_points);

Comment: alert(response.acc_points)

Comment: either `$response = $acc_points['acc_points'];`  or in jquery try like:- `alert(response.acc_points)`

Comment: Thanks guys! That fixed it.

Comment: note, for error condition you should `$response = "'Failed. Please try again.'";` - otherwise your response will be `jsonpcallback(Failed. Please try again.)` - which is not valid javascript